# mysql getting last_insert_id() in a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, lastinsertid

It's my understanding that when you call last_insert_id() it goes by connections, so you'll get the id of the last row inserted on the same connection where last_insert_id() is called, right?

So what if I call last_insert_id() in an 'AFTER INSERT' trigger?

What I want to do is basically this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger
AFTER INSERT ON sometable
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO anothertable (id, lastup) VALUES (last_insert_id(), NOW());
END $$
```

It's very important that the id in 'anothertable' is the same as in 'sometable'
Would this work or should I create a stored procedure instead that inserts into both tables?

Or possibly there is some, in the trigger, to get the values from the insert statement that caused the trigger to fire? I haven't found anything about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use `NEW.{id column name}` to refer to the last insert id (so for example `NEW.id` if the auto increment column is called `id`.)

Comment: This seems to be working. That NEW keyword was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks.