# MySQL Triggers last_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql

I have table 1 in which has id as autoincrement.
Table 2 has a foreign key relationship to Table 1, in which I need that value generated from table 1 to be inserted into table 2

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `baemer_emr`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `baemer_emr`.`after_insert_log` AFTER INSERT ON `baemer_emr`.`table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (last_insert_id() , something);
END$$
```

It is working, but is displaying the number before. For example

Insert into table 1, id = 15. In table 2 returns 14. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `last_insert_id()` try using `new.id` or whatever you named your primary key column.

Comment: @Skynight, don't put your email address in a question, unless you liked to get spammed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql getting last_insert_id() in a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499389/mysql-getting-last-insert-id-in-a-trigger)

Comment: @Johan, thanks hadn't noticed.

Comment: @mellamokb, definitely the duplicate thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql getting last\_insert\_id() in a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499389/mysql-getting-last-insert-id-in-a-trigger)

Answer (score 7):

In a trigger you have 2 virtual tables, called `NEW` and `OLD`
You can use these virtual table to get the newly inserted values.
The `OLD` virtual table only works in the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers obviously.
And the DELETE trigger does not have `NEW` table.

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `baemer_emr`$$

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_log AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (NEW.id, something);
END$$
```

Note that `NEW.id`  _(assuming that id is a auto_increment field)_  will **not yet** be set in a `before insert` trigger, just one of those little pitfalls to avoid.

Comment: Will that NEW.id be affected if for example, there are 3 more transactions in the meantime? And instead of returning 12 returns 17?

Comment: @Skynight In the `after` triggers NEW is read-only and the trigger runs `FOR EACH ROW` so you don't have to worry 'bout that :-).

Comment: thanks a lot and one more question...how can I tell the difference between NEW.id from table 1 or table 2? if they have the same column name for example @Johan