# how can i add primary key value which is auto incremented to another column in php?

Tags: php, sql

I have a tree and I want to I have a table which has an id also, I want to use this id by adding to another column.

clearly,
I want to add id column'value to parent_root column.

```
   sql = "INSERT INTO agac_menu (id,isim,aciklama,parent_id,parent_root,yetki,sira,tip,created)
        VALUES (NULL,'".$isim."','".$aciklama."','".$parent_id."','".$parent_root."','".$yetki."','".$sira."','".$tip."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was MySQL (yes, I know it was more generic) you could use a trigger: [MySQL Triggers last_insert_id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715197/mysql-triggers-last-insert-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the same query--the auto incremented id doesn't exist until the record is inserted.  After your query runs in php, grab the last insert id and run an update query.