# Last_insert_id returns 0 for autoincremented column with letters and numbers

Tags: mysql, lastinsertid

I used a trigger to generate id: `ug01`, `ug02`... I want to insert them into the foreign key column but `last_insert_id()`  returns 0 creating an error. How can I get the value of the "last_insert_id"  as it is in the primary key column.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499389/mysql-getting-last-insert-id-in-a-trigger

Comment: Generating an id yourself makes no sense at all. Also, `last_insert_id()` returns the value generated by `auto_increment` field. You can't use `last_insert_id()` to retrieve some random id **you** generated. You should *always* use a numeric id. If you need other characters for whatever reason, save them in another column and then concatenate the id and alphabet part while `SELECT`-ing. That will let you have your alphanumeric id, and MySQL will play along and won't have any issues caused by a weird primary key.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a `BIGINT (64-bit)` value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the most recently executed *INSERT* statement to affect such a column.

In your case, you are inserting the id, so an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is not generated, thus `LAST_INSERT_ID` returns `0`.

Cross check this by execute *MySql* command: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: How do I get the value to insert into the foreign key column as it is in the primary key column

Comment: Or do I play safe by reverting to just autoincrement?

Comment: Are you using UUID() generated value with trigger?

Comment: here's the ref for last_insert_id, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id